# How to send image in html formatted email in android?

Tags: android, html, image, email, android-intent

I want to send a html formatted email though my application,
but styles for all tags are not supported while sending email.

here is my Java code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Look What I Found!");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
      Html.fromHtml(mMessage)
);
startActivity(emailIntent);`
```

Here is my html, What I want to send:

```html
"<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>Document</title> </head> <body> <center> <table style="width: 600px; margin:0 auto" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr> <td> <table> <tr> <td> <img src="https://www.twinspires.com/sites/twinspires.com/files/header-600x123.jpg" alt="Churchill Downs" style="display: block;width: 600px;height: 123px;"> </td> </tr> </table> <table style="padding:40px 0px;"> <tr> <td style="width: 50px;"> </td> <td> <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serf;text-align: justify; font-style: 14px;">View this shared article from the Churchill Downs Incorporated Magazine $title. Download the official lifestyle app of Churchill Downs – "Club 1875" to access the elegant world of Thoroughbred racing and the Kentucky Derby. Stay up to date on fashion, food, celebrities and some of the most recognizable names in the industry. Club 1875 is your behind the scenes guide to the most exciting two minutes in sports – whether you’re at the track or far away! </p> </td> <td style="width: 50px;"> </td> </tr> </table> <center> <table> <tr> <td> <img src="https://www.twinspires.com/sites/twinspires.com/files/logo-235x98-02.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 235px; height: 98px;" alt="CLUB 1875"> </td> </tr> </table> </center> <center> <table> <tr> <td> <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/club-1875/id1171549047?mt=8" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.twinspires.com/sites/twinspires.com/files/icon-148x40-02.jpg" alt="Download Here" style="display: block;width:148px;height: 40px; "></a> </td> </tr> </table> </center> <center> <table style="padding-top: 40px;"> <tr> <td> <img src="https://www.twinspires.com/sites/twinspires.com/files/footer-558x278.jpg" style="display: block;width: 558px;height: 278px;" a"
```

And here is output while I send email:

[image]

Comment: Please help me to get ride of this..

Comment: I also faces same issue with <img>

Comment: Can you post your code that you've done so far

Comment: emailIntent.setType("text/html");, put this line in your code

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.setType("text/html");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Look What I Found!");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(mMessage));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

I also have done that but didn't work...
@Bhavnik

Comment: Can you try `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of `>` and `<` respectively only for img tag.

Comment: If I add &gt; and &lt; then whole img tag is converted and prints as a string in my email body. 
@Muhammad Babar

Comment: `Html.fromHtml` will convert them to equal character i.e > and <. Try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
String mailId="yourmail@gmail.com";
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",mailId, null)); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text here"); 
// you can use simple text like this
// emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body text here"); 
// or get fancy with HTML like this
emailIntent.putExtra(
         Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
         Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
             .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
         .append("<a>http://www.google.com</a>")
         .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
         .toString())
     );
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: So every time html code will be same? or different?

Comment: Yes, Which I have posted above will be same for my every email.

Comment: Okay then did you try to make file of `HTML` and then share that file?

Comment: `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getPath()));` take file from accets also

Comment: Here is my Intent:


  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/html");
        File file = new File("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, ""));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143467/discussion-between-jaydip-umaretiya-and-ankitakoladiya).